# Hive - Efficient join of two tables

Tags: optimization, join, hive, buckets

I am joining two large tables in Hive (one is over 1 billion rows, one is about 100 million rows) like so:

```
create table joinedTable as select t1.id, ... from t1 join t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id);
```

I have bucketed the two tables in the same way, clustering by id into 100 buckets for each, but the query is still taking a long time.

Any suggestions on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you bucketed the data by the join keys, you could use the Bucket Map Join. For that the amount of buckets in one table must be a multiple of the amount of buckets in the other table. It can be activated by executing `set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;` before the query. If the tables don't meet the conditions, Hive will simply perform the normal Inner Join.

If both tables have the same amount of buckets and the data is sorted by the bucket keys, Hive can perform the faster Sort-Merge Join. To activate it, you have to execute the following commands:

```
set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.BucketizedHiveInputFormat;
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge=true;
```

You can find some visualizations of the different join techniques under https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27362054/Hive+Summit+2011-join.pdf.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Do indexes help at all in Hive? ie. if I indexed both t1 and t2 by id?

Comment: Indexes wouldn't improve the performance in a join. They're used for retrieving single rows, for example in `WHERE id=123`. Buckets are the best choice here.

Comment: You can specify the amount of buckets when you create the table by appending this: `CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 192 BUCKETS`

Comment: Sorry, I was reading that wrong. The column values are hashed by the amount of buckets. Bucketing the id column, which should have distinct values, should ensure uniformity.
By using the Bucket Map Join, Hive performs the common Map-side Join on the buckets. So the number of buckets depends on your table's size and the value of `hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize`, which in this case specifies the maximum size of the buckets for the Map-side Join in bytes. I would recommend to better use more buckets, as you can't guarantee evenly populated buckets.

Answer (score 16):

As i see it the answer is a bit more complicated than what @Adrian Lange offered.

First you must understand a very important difference between BucketJoin and Sort-Merge Bucket Join (SMBJ):

To perform a **bucketjoin** "the amount of buckets in one table must be a multiple of the amount of buckets in the other table" as stated before and in addition `hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin` must be set to true.
Issuing a join, hive will convert it into a **bucketjoin** if the above condition take place **BUT** pay attention that hive will not enforce the bucketing! this means that creating the table bucketed isn't enough for the table to actually be bucketed into the specified amount of buckets as hive doesn't enforce this unless `hive.enforce.bucketing` is set to true (which means that the amount of buckets actually is set by the amount of reducers in the final stage of the query inserting data into the table).
As from the performance side, please note that when using a **bucketjoin** a **single task** reads the "smaller" table into the distributed cache before the mappers access it and do the join - This stage would probably be very very long and ineffective when your table has ~100m rows!
After wards the join will be done same as in a regular join done in the reducers.

To perform a **SMBJ** both tables have to have the exact same amount of buckets , on the same columns and sorted by these columns in addition to setting `hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge` to true.
As in the previous optimization, Hive doesn't enforce the bucketing and the sorting but rather assumes you made sure that the tables are actually bucketed and sorted (not only by definition but by setting `hive.enforce.sorting` or manually sorting the data while inserting it) - This is very important as it **may lead to wrong results in both cases**.
As from the performace side, this optimization is way more efficient for the following reasons :

1. Each mapper reads both buckets and there is no single task contention for distributed cache loading
2. The join being performed is a merge-sort join as the data is already sorted which is highly more efficient.

Please note the following considerations :

- in both cases `set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.BucketizedHiveInputFormat;`
  should be executed
- in both cases a `/*+ MAPJOIN(b) */` should be applied in the query (right after the `select` and where `b` is the smaller table)
- **How many buckets?**
  This should be viewed from this angle : the consideration should be applied strictly to the bigger table as it has more impact from this direction and latter the configuration will be applied to the smaller table as a must. I think as a rule of thumb each bucket should contain between 1 and 3 blocks, probably somewhere near 2 blocks. so if your block size is 256MB it seams reasonable to me to have ~512MB of data in each bucket in the bigger table so this becomes a simple division issue.

Also, don't forget that these optimizations alone won't always guarantee a faster query time.
Lets say you choose to do a SMBJ, this adds the cost of sorting 2 tables prior to running the join - so the more times you will run your query the less you are "paying" for this sorting stage.

Sometimes, a simple join will lead to the best performance and none of the above optimization will help and you will have to optimize the regular join process either in the application/logical level or by tuning MapReduce / Hive settings like memory usage / parallelism etc.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Its  a must criteria "the amount of buckets in one table must be a multiple of the amount of buckets in the other table" for map bucket join,We can have same number of buckets also.